# Dropping a User, Handling Blank Default Privileges in Redshift, pg_default_acl

Tags: amazon-redshift, privileges, user-permissions

I am looking to reset permissions in a Development environment and I noticed two users I could not drop. I checked all of the permissions etc and the only reference to these users I found was in pg_default_acl.

```
select * from pg_default_acl;
```

Returns:

```
defacluser   |   defaclnamespace   |   defaclobjtype   |   defaclacl
----------------------------------------------------------------------
101          |   0                 |               r   |   {}
122          |   0                 |               r   |   {}
```

Are these empty permissions preventing me from dropping these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a resolution when I came across these admin scripts on github:

[awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/user_to_be_dropped_privs.sql)

The issue ended up being default privileges that were granted to other users.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error with which the drop fails? These users could be owning tables or views or functions.

You can find the tables with `select * from pg_tables where tableowner in ('one', 'two');`

The views with: `select * from pg_views where viewowner in ('one', 'two');`

The functions with: `select * from pg_proc where proowner in (select usesysid from pg_user where usename in ('one', 'two'));`

And then your users may own schemas too:
`select * from pg_namespace where nspowner in (select usesysid from pg_user where usename in ('one', 'two'));`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I apologize I should have posted my solution. The issue ended up requiring me to change the default privileges of other users that gave permissions to the user I was trying to drop.